# Migrando Angular 1 hacia Angular 2

Tags: ionic2, angular

soy nuevo en Angular 2 , quiero migrar este código de Angular 1 a Angular2, podrían por favor darme una idea de como hacerlo.

```
    // Forgot Password
$scope.passwordDialog = function($event) {
  prompty({
    title: 'Password Recovery',
    label: 'Enter your email address',
    type: 'email',
    submitText: 'Send',
    required: true,
    event: $event
  })
    .then(function(email) {
      return superlogin.forgotPassword(email);
    })
    .then(function() {
      toasty('Check your email!');
    }, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        toasty(err.error);
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta que estas en SO en español

Comment: Please translate your question this site is in Spanish

Comment: @RaulCacacho Listo!

Answer (score -1):

`Angular 2` o Simplemente `Angular` no tiene nada que ver con `Angular JS`, yo te recomiendo que investigues o busques un tutorial acerca de Angular y Typescript.

Y como respuesta a la pregunta podrias instalar [SWAL2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2) este componente contiene muchas de las funcionalidades que necesitas.